# How can I use an element from an object in array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an arrayList with objects. And those objects have random numbers. I want to use some of them after, but I don't know how I can get to it. 
here's my code :

```
     for(var l=0; l<20; l++){
        o.x=Math.random();
        o.y=Math.random();
        tab3[l]=[o.x,o.y];

      }
```

So I want to use for example o.x from the first object in the array (tab[0]). How is that possible? and if I wish to add some more elements, like o.z to tab[0], how can I do that ?

Comment: The iteration time _value_ of `o.x` is stored in `tab3[l][0]`, the array doesn't contain objects.

Comment: you are doing right, tab3[0].push(o.z), since you are treating tab3 to be an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

why do you need to put o.x and o.y in an array? the way you currently have it you could also call tab[0][0].x and tab[0][1].y but that doesn't make any sense to do it that way.

you could do it like this

```
for(var l=0; l<20; l++){
    tab3[l]=[Math.random(),Math.random()];
  }
```

and you would call it like tab3[0][0] or tab3[0][1]

or since i don't know what your variable o is you could also do

```
for(var l=0; l<20; l++){
    o.x=Math.random();
    o.y=Math.random();
    tab3[l]=[o];
  }
```

then you would call tab[0].x or tab[0].y

when you want to add z you would add

`tab[0].z = Math.random();`